# ajax inconsistent on Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, cross-browser

-EDIT-

I have tried to add some error handling to the failing function with `error: function(jqXhr, status, error)` but `jqXhr.responseText` is empty so I guess I'm still not handling errors properly.

-/EDIT-

I am new to ajax and have to modify an existing site with these two existing ajax functions, both of which are working fine in Chrome, IE and FF but only the first works in Safari. The second one fails but the error handler (which I guess wasn't set up properly?) doesn't tell me much:

```
// works in each browser
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: apiBaseUrl + 'GetCountries',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: parseCountries,
    error: function(){
        $('.errorMessage').append('<p>' + errorMessage + '</p>');
    }
});

// does not work in Safari
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: apiBaseUrl + 'GetStandardTexts?page=login',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: displayRegisteredAlert,
    error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
        var err = eval("(" + jqXhr.responseText + ")"); 
        alert(err.Message);    
    }  
});
```

the only real difference between them that I can see is the URL in the second contains and additional parameter, `?page=login`.

Comment: In the first ajax, there is "cache: false" definition, did you try adding that to the second ajax call too?

Comment: also, is the function "displayRegisteredAlert" that is called on success in the second ajax call is actually defined?

Comment: Yes, and called OK on other browsers than Safari .

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in the second function - you need to add another closing curly bracket ("}") before the ending bracket (");") of the function.

Comment: That was a typo introduced when I changed the error handler - edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work. I'm not entirely sure why but adding `async:false` solved it for Safari. Not required for other browsers.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,  // only required on Safari
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: apiBaseUrl + 'GetStandardTexts?page=login',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: displayRegisteredAlert,
    error: function(jqXhr, status, error){
    var err = eval("(" + jqXhr.responseText + ")"); 
    alert(err.Message);    
  }  
});
```